# Use Ajax in Fat free framework to render route every 5 seconds

Tags: php, ajax, setinterval, fat-free-framework

I need for help in fat free
I want to use ajax  to render to a specific route every 5 seconds
But I can't console any data the ajax page

and this is my php code :

```
elseif ($this->session->isRole(UserRole::TRAINEE)) {

                    $this->assets->addJs('meeting.js');
                    $f3->push('init.js', 'Meetings');
                    $f3->set('name', $name);
                    
                    $f3->set('joinUrl', 'meeting/' . $meetingId);

                    $this->render();
                }
```

and this is my ajax code

```
let Meetings = function () {

 let joinMeeting = function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.join-meeting', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        let meetingId = data.meeting_id;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/meeting/' + meetingId,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.joinUrl === 'none') {
                    noty({text: 'Could not join the requested meeting.', type: 'error'});
                } else {
                    setInterval(window.open(result.joinUrl, '_blank'), 5000);
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR) {
                noty({text: 'Application error', type: 'error'});
            }
        });
    });
};


return {
    //main function to initiate the module
    init: function () {
        joinMeeting();

    }
}
}();
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is this a JS problem (where the request is not sent properly by the browser), or a PHP problem (where the server does not handle the request properly)?

Comment: I used another way to complete the task

Answer (score 1):

If you render a page, the page is loaded and the script is reloaded again and set interval is never ejecuted.